# Change Detection for text interpolation with nested classes

Tags: angular

I have a typical constellation of a *list component* and an *item component*. The item component has a property 'username'. Let us assume I want to change this property from outside the item component like here (see setUsername() for 'Bob'):

my-item.component.ts:

```
export class MyItemComponent implements OnInit {
  username: string = 'not set';
  setUsername() { this.username = 'Alice'; }
  /* ... */
}
```

my-item.component.html:

```
<p>User: {{ username }}</p>
<button (click)="setUsername()">This works</button>
```

my-list.component.ts:

```
export class MyListComponent implements OnInit {
  items: MyItemComponent[] = [
    new MyItemComponent(),
    new MyItemComponent()
  ];

  setUsername() {
    this.items[0].username = 'Bob';
  }
  /* ... */
}
```

my-list.component.html:

```
<app-my-item *ngFor="let i of items"></app-my-item>
<button (click)="setUsername()">This does not work</button>
```

My problem is the *text interpolation* of username. There is no update triggered which I thought it would do automatically. What are my options to make a new username visible after it changed?

Answer (score 0):

```
setUsername() {
    this.items[0].username = 'Bob';
    ///this will trigger change detection
    this.items = [...this.items];
  }
```